# Run SBT in background on ZSH

Tags: sbt, zsh

I am using a linux VM on cloud. I SSH into the VM and I see that it uses zsh.

I want to run "SBT RUN" in background so that I can close the session and go home and my code keeps running.

I am using `fork:=true`

I have tried the following

```
sbt run &!
nohup sbt run </dev/null &
```

Nothing seems to work. it never launches the JVM. But if I do `sbt run` I can see that it launches the forked JVM correctly.

Once again

```
1. ZSH
2. SBT RUN
3. Fork:=true
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it this way at all, but you could also try `bgRun` task. If it doesn't work, you can use sbt-assembly to produce a self-contained jar and run it separately.

Comment: Let me give bgRun a spin. I wonder if that will survive me closing the ssh session. will revert

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is typically done via utilities like `screen` or `tmux`, which then allow you to re-attach to an already running shell, not just a single process.

Searching a bit, I [found this serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process) that mentions `disown` and `reptyr`, both of which might be more applicable to specifically detaching a running `sbt` instance and then re-attaching.